# Notification issues

Tags: android, updates, android-notifications

I have developed application which shows Notification on receiving of new update from server.

On arriving of update from server, i can see generated new notification on Device notification area.

A problem which I am facing is that Notification time gets update each time on show.

1. Is there any way to know about already exist Notification of app?
2. I want to regenerate Notification if its not exist

I made R&D but didn't get any method to get existing Notifications which are in device notification area.

Answer (score 2):

To set up a notification so it can be updated, issue it with a notification ID by calling `NotificationManager.notify(ID, notification).`

To update this notification once you've issued it, update or create a `NotificationCompat.Builder` object, build a `Notification` object from it, and issue the `Notification` with the same ID you used previously.

Answer (score 0):

Its a noficcation ID iSsue...you are get notifications with different ID...

if you do like this :

```
NotificationManager.notify(3000, notification);
```

and when you again call same method you will not get another notification..

Comment: I am using a same Notification Id and its not making multiple notification. But problem with Time which is displayed by system on  right side of Notification. I dont want to update time on calling of notify() if Notification still exist in bar.